# Google Maps api show grey screen

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am trying to get on my website the gmaps with few markers but i am getting the grey screen or partially grey screen.Before, I used google maps API the same way and everythings works fine. If you can help me I would be grateful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Zadanie 7</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDPAizH-vug5nDhwYi0C5Km-pCiQRx7wpY"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="map" style="height: 500px;">

</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
            <h4>Zadanie 6 Martin Kranec</h4>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="firstpage.php">Prvá Stránka</a></li>
                <li><a href="secondpage.php">Druhá Stránka</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="thirdpage.php">Tretia Stránka</a></li>
            </ul><br>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class='container-fluid'><div class='table-responsive'><table class='table'><thead><tr><th>Vlajka</th><th>Štát</th><th>Počet Navštevníkov</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>World</td><td>World</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td><img class='flag' src='http://www.geonames.org/flags/x/sk.gif'></td><td><a href='countrystatistics.php?countrycode=sk'>Slovensko</a></td><td>2</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<footer class="container-fluid">
    <p>&COPY;Martin Kranec Webové technológie</p>
</footer>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    var lat=[]; 
    var lon=[];
    lat.push(48.15);
    lon.push(17.1167);
    lat.push(48.1704);
    lon.push(17.4209);
</script>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        //alert(lat[1]);
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(89, -25),
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
        var count = lat.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var myLatLng = {lat: lat[i], lng: lon[i]};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: ''
            });
        }
    }
    initMap();
    //initMap();
</script>
<!--<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDPAizH-vug5nDhwYi0C5Km-pCiQRx7wpY&callback=initMap"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my website where I work on this project http://147.175.98.165/zadanie7/thirdpage.php

Comment: Usually I see the grey map bug when the div that your adding the map to, is invisible when the code executes, or the code executed too early before the maps API was ready.  You can pass a callback function to the google api script, in this case, your initMap() function. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDPAizH-vug5nDhwYi0C5Km-pCiQRx7wpY&callback=initMap` and remove the manual invoke of initMap.

Comment: Yeah i try it but the result was the same,you can see that it was commented

Comment: Check your network log, does it show images getting blocked when you scroll around the grey map?

Comment: What is `style.css`? (`style.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`)  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Yeah, how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps has a lot of race conditions.  I use this code a lot to display them instead.  This code should be in a ready event like jquery ready.

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (!document.getElementById('google-maps')) {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        var link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDPAizH-vug5nDhwYi0C5Km-pCiQRx7wpY&callback=mapsFinishedLoading";
        fileref.setAttribute("async", "async");
        fileref.setAttribute("defer", "defer");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", link);
        fileref.setAttribute("id", 'google-maps');
        window.mapsFinishedLoading = resolve;
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    } else {
        resolve();
    }
}).then(function (result) {
    //Your map should be available now
    mapOptions={};//put your options here
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
});
```

Make sure your map div is visible before calling

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);`